Windows Server 2022 Hyper-V DHCP Lease code 83
I need help with Hyper-v Windows Server 2022.
Recently Spinned up a new Cluster on Win 2022 and I am facing Network challenges with the VMs not seeing the Network. But only the ones deployed without Desktop Experience GUI.
Every time I try to assign a static IP it gives me the error below:
Setting NIC to static IP…

Failed to release DHCP lease.

Result code: 83

Method name: ReleaseDHCPLease

Attempted the workaround from this post: https://blog.cslim.nl/index.php/blog/sysadminning/17-windows-server/49-windows-server-core-failed-to...
But the issue still persist. I need Help

Have you tried to disconnect the VM from the virtual switch before trying the process? On Hyper-V open the VM settings and keep the vNIC, but disconnect it from any virtual switch. Then open the VM and try to change to static IP.

Hi @ViniciusApolinario I have tried this process. The moment I disconnect the Virtual Network Adapter, sconfig does not see the adapter at all. However, powershell sees the Network Adapter disconnected.

An update, copied the VM to a Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V and the network works fine. The bug seems to be on Windows Server 2022. Not sure which CU will resolve this on the Win Server 2022

You could try a registry way. Get-NetAdapter|Select Name, DeviceID, go to HKLM\\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\<DeviceID>, set EnableDhcp to 0, and define IPAddress, SubnetMask, DefaultGateway and NameServer values to what you need (note that the later one is REG_SZ not REG_MULTI_SZ).  This should work
